# ERROR: type "dblink_pkey_results" already exists when installing pgWatch

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I copied pgwatch into www root.
Then I installed extensions with the following command:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

Then server restarted. Then I went to pgwatch database with the below command:

```
psql -U postgres -d pgwatch
```

And issued the following command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Without any error everything worked fine, but when I went to install it through `http://localhost/pgwatch/setup.php` I entered specified parameter. In the third step I received the following error:

```
ERROR: type "dblink_pkey_results" already exists
```

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
I dropped pgWatch table and installed everything from scratch.

Comment: Hi, now i am trying to install pgwatch, can you post a blog showing how to install pgwatch?

Comment: @francs, that would be a good article. I'll post that in www.bugx.ir blog.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message after running 
create extension dblink;
The below fix worked for me:
go to the "YourDatabaseName"-->schemas--> public-->types-->right click on type "dblink_pkey_results", select drop.
open SQL editor and run the query being connected to your database
create extension dblink;

Comment: And how is that different from phpGeek's answer "*I dropped pgWatch table*"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I encountered the same problem with dblink but hadn't pgWatch installed. Google led me to this answer and it helped. So this answer is more universal.

Comment: Deleting the type object is indeed a more universal answer.